# Find the maximum flow in any network by a given algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph, ford-fulkerson

can you help me with the following problem?:

Suppose we have an algorithm to solve the problem of maximum flow in a flow network in which each node's outdegree is at most 2.
I need to show how to use this algorithm to solve the problem of maximum flow in any network.

If this is a repetition then kindly redirect me to relevant answers.

Thank you all

Comment: Hint: Find a scheme to transform a random network into a network in which the node's outdegree is at most 2.

Comment: What do you mean by 'show how to use this algorithm'? The answer to that could be as simple as "runFordFolkerson(myFlowNetwork)", or maybe you're looking for something along the lines of listing the steps the algorithm will go through?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in [a computer science oriented site](http://cs.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @n.m., I'm new to StackOverflow and I just want to understand how it is intended to work. Based on what you just said, am I correct in my interpretation that StackOverflow is for programming questions as opposed to computer science questions?

Comment: @TowerFan i theory yes, in practice less so (I'm trying to make practice agree with theory better).

Answer (score 1):

It is indeed possible to transform the graph in such a way that the out-degree of each node is at most 2, and the maximum flow in the transformed graph is equal to the maximum flow in the initial graph.

One such transformation is described below. Assume we have a node whose out degree is larger than 2. Then we can add as many intermediary nodes as the out-degree of this node and connect them in the way depicted in the following image.

[image: ![transformation]

The infinite capacity edges ensure that we can send the same flow as initially from A to any of its successors. The edges from `X` nodes to `B` nodes ensure that we can not send a flow larger than it was initially possible.

By repeating this transformation for each node with out-degree larger than 2 we obtain a graph where each node has out-degree at most 2, and whose maximum flow is equal to the maximum flow of the initial graph.

Comment: Welcome, I'm glad it's helpful! Also, in case any aspect is still unclear, please let me know.

Comment: I want now to prove the correctness of this algorithm. My idea is to show that the capacity of a cut in the new network can be infinity, or an "old value" of capacity in the original network. therefore, the capacity of the min-cut in the new network remains the same, and from the Max-flow min-cut theorem i get that the max-flow also remains the same. Am I right?

Comment: That is an interesting proof and it looks correct. To be formal we still need to find an argument that takes the topology of the auxiliary graph into account to prove that indeed we can find the same value of the cut in the initial graph. (I have no doubt that this is true)

Comment: A finite s-t cut in the new graph will only contain edges of the form `X->B` (*i.e.* from an auxiliary node to an initial node -- I assume here, in order to make the discussion more uniform, that we insert auxiliary nodes not only when we have a node with out-degee>2, but for every node, towards its successors). Let's define, for each auxiliary node `X` as in image, `root(X) = A`. Our finite s-t cut that contains only edges of the form `X->B` will have an associated equal s-t cut with associated sets `S` and `T` obtained by removing auxiliary nodes, and edges in the cut of form `root(X)->B`